# Mysql sum and max combination with yesterday data

Tags: php, mysql

Hi every this might be silly question but cant figure it out. i have a table with these data:

```
+--------------+--------+--------+---------------+-------------+
| company_code | ltp    | ycp    | datetime      | total_value |
+--------------+--------+--------+---------------+-------------+
| ABC          | 291.00 | 342.00 | 9/25/13 10:30 |    12540    |   
| ABC          | 344.00 | 342.00 | 9/25/13 10:31 |    15400    |
+--------------+--------+--------+---------------+-------------+
```

as you see data is updating in every minute, what i need to find the change in price which is (ltp-ycp)/ycp. so I write this query :

```
SELECT
  company_code, max(ltp), ycp, sum((max(ltp) - ycp)/ycp) as change  
FROM eod_stock 
GRPUP BY company_code 
ORDER BY change DESC;
```

but this gives error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to    your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'change  FROM eod_stock GRPUP BY company_code ORDER BY change DESC'
```

dont find the solution as i need the last trading price - yesterday price(ycp) but dont know how to use sum with max.

another problem i need to find the last days total trade mean here in table shows 9/25/2013 but i need last inserted total trade of 9/24/2013

i used 
    select max(total_trade), datetime - interval from eod_stock limit 10; also getting error. can anyone figure it how can escape from this error?

Comment: Change is a reserved word use another alias or use back ticks.

Comment: i used chnge even no luck.

Comment: The ycp is the same for each day?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following

```
    SELECT
     `c_code`, `m_lcp`, `ycp`,sum(`change`)
    from
    (
     select `company_code` as `c_code`, max(`ltp`) as `m_lcp`, `ycp`,(max(`ltp`) -   `ycp`)/`ycp` as `change`  from `eod_stock` 
    group by `company_code`
    ) `e1`
    order by `change` DESC;
```

Comment: ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function
 can you tell why?

Comment: I have edited the previous query,You are trying sum and max together and creating the issue, the above new query should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  `company_code`, max(`ltp`), `ycp`, (max(`ltp`) - `ycp`)/`ycp`) as `change`  
FROM `eod_stock` 
GROUP BY `company_code` 
ORDER BY `change` DESC;
```

You have written the keyword `GROUP` wrong

Edit: No need for SUM() ;)

Comment: getting this error ERROR 1111 (HY000): Invalid use of group function

Comment: Sorry my mistake, fixed :)